# NoSuchElementException on reopening the scanner within a method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception, system.in

Here's a reduced version of the code that's throwing the exception.

```
static String s1;
static String s2;

static void getString(String s) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    s = sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getString(s1);
    getString(s2);
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
>   found     at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)    at
>   temp.Temp.getString(Temp.java:13)

I'm calling the `getString` method twice, and on second call it breaks on:

```
s = sc.nextLine();
```

Now, I understand that removing the `sc.close()` line solves the problem (and making `sc` a static variable probably, too). What I need to grasp is WHY this is the case.

I read the specification of the `scanner` class but couldn't deduce. I also read several posts on this exception including  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063047/nosuchelementexception) one, which says that closing the scanner also closes the underlying stream. But I'm creating a new scanner and reopening the stream with every method call, no?

Comment: You're not creating a new stream. You're always using the same stream: System.in. When it's closed, it's closed.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes, noted it, just corrected this to 'reopening'. The question still persists, though. Or you mean that, once closed, it can't be reopened no matter what?

Comment: When you close the scanner it closes the stream it is using, that is System.in

Comment: No, you're not "reopening" anything. A stream cannot be reopened, and there is no "reopening" anywhere. You're using a single stream, and when it's closed, it's closed. Forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as "reopening a stream". The only thing you can do is create a new stream, with a new `Scanner`, and optionally place it in the same variable.

Once you close `sc`, you also close the underlying `System.in` stream. Creating a new `Scanner` on top of it can't "reopen" it, and since the stream is closed, you get this exception.

To make a long story short - while it's definitely a good practice to close resources when you're done with them, you shouldn't close `System.in` (or any scanner based on it).

Answer (score 1):

You can not "re-open" System.in, System.out or System.err as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286690/in-java-is-it-possible-to-re-open-system-in-after-closing-it)

As another solution to this you can use CloseShieldInputStream  which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in)